# How to not show "Friend who using the app" in FB registration plugin

Tags: api, facebook

I use iframe version of FB registration plugins. It shows the friends who registered to this app near the register button.

Is there a way to disable this panel?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, but that sounds like a good suggestion to submit to Facebook.  Add it to http://developer.facebook.com/bugs as a wishlist item.